# Разделение компонентов между контекстами

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Я читал про разницу между web-контекстом и контекстом приложения. Вроде разницу понимаю, но постоянно натыкаюсь на грабли. В дескрипторе развёртывания указал конфигурации контекстов

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

В servlet-context.xml постарался оставить только слой представления

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

В root-context.xml наоборот хочу загрузить всё, кроме контроллеров

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

и importами подключаю конфигурацию слоя доступа к данным, транзакций, безопасности, кэша и т.п.

Только аннотация `@Transactional`, например, отказывается работать в **сервисном** слое до тех пор, пока я тег `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` не вынесу в servlet-context.xml. То есть бины помеченные аннотациями `@Service` и `@Repository` почему-то загружены в web-контекст? Почему так? Или я всё-таки неправильно понимаю разницу между контекстами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конфигурация `<context:component-scan>` по умолчанию ищет классы, расположенные в `base-package` и вложенных пакетах и помеченные аннотацией `@Component` (и всеми её наследниками - `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` и т.д.). Элементы `<context:include-filter>` и `<context:exclude-filter>` лишь расширяют или сужают критерий поиска, а не заменяют его.

Конфигурация

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" 
                            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

заставит Spring искать в пакете `com.example` классы, помеченные аннотацией `@Component`, а также классы, помеченные аннотацией `org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`.

Для того чтобы запретить Spring'у искать аннотации по умолчанию, нужно к конфигурации добавить атрибут `use-default-filters="false"`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
                            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Теперь Spring будет искать только классы, помеченные аннотацией `@Controller`.

В вашей конфигурации в обоих контекстах полностью сканировался пакет `com.example` (в `root-context` - за исключением контроллеров). Бины сервисного слоя были созданы сначала в `root-context` (и для них было включено управление транзакциями), а затем ещё раз - в `servlet-context` (для них управление транзакциями включено не было). Когда Spring ищет зависимости, чтобы внедрить их в бины, он сначала ищет их в текущем контексте (для контроллеров это `servlet-context`), а если не находит - в родительском (`root-context`). Так как в `servlet-context` у вас нашлись бины нужных классов, в `root-context` Spring не полез, и в контроллеры заинжектились бины без управления транзакциями.

Comment: Разве параметр `include-filter` не сужает критерии загружаемых бинов только до тех, которые в нём указаны?

Comment: Не сужает. Наоборот, при отсутствии `use-default-filters="false"`, он расширяет критерий, используемый по умолчанию.

Comment: Документацию на XML-конфигурацию я не нашёл, но нашёл аналог в Java-конфигурации. В её [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#includeFilters--) это явно прописано. Spring - достаточно консистентный фреймворк, так что можно ожидать, что аналогичные параметры будут вести себя одинаково и в XML и в Java конфигурации.

Comment: Это интересно! Я попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, работает!